# Stop duplicate emails with different subscriber keys from entering a journey at different intervals

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

I have a journey that is triggered by an automation that runs hourly. At the moment, I have the issue that issue where a contact has the same email address but different subscriber key. As a result there are some contacts who receive the same email more than once in the same day usually an hour or two apart.

I have been able to dedupe the data extension if an email address in the same hour but how do I stop a contact from entering if they are part of a later refresh?

Comment: Do you mean stoping the same contact from entring the same journey multiple times?

Comment: It is the same contact. Duplicate contacts have same email address but they have different subscriber key so Journey Builder treats them as separate entities.

Answer (score -1):

Use Evaluate new records only as a Journey setting entry. do not overwrite the DE.

Comment: Will that work if Journey Builder is evaluating records on the Subscriber Key level?

Comment: yes it will work.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned by Ankit, if you OVERWRITE, it will reset the 'High Watermark' as well. So the above solution must work.

Comment: This will not accomplish in solving for your use case